# Failing to import itertools in Python 3.5.2

Tags: python, python-2.7, pycharm, python-3.5, python-itertools

I am new to Python. I am trying to import izip_longest from itertools. But I am not able to find the import "itertools" in the preferences in Python interpreter. I am using Python 3.5.2. It gives me the below error-

```
from itertools import izip_longest
ImportError: cannot import name 'izip_longest'
```

Please let me know what is the right course of action. I have tried Python 2.7 too and ended up with same problem. Do I need to use lower version Python.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

`izip_longest` was *renamed* to [`zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) in Python 3 (note, no `i` at the start), import that instead:

```
from itertools import zip_longest
```

and use that name in your code.

If you need to write code that works both on Python 2 and 3, catch the `ImportError` to try the other name, then rename:

```
try:
    # Python 3
    from itertools import zip_longest
except ImportError:
    # Python 2
    from itertools import izip_longest as zip_longest

# use the name zip_longest
```

Comment: Thanks @Martijn. Changing it to zip_longest solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

One of the simple way of importing any feature is through object importing(ex: *import itertools as it*) unless you want to hide other features. Since features in modules does change according to python version, Easy way to check whether the feature is present in module is through *dir()* function. 

*import itertools as it
dir(it)*

It'll list all the features in it