# Failing to import module named 'version' because izip_longest

Tags: python, pycharm, python-module

I'm trying to import a module named version, but every time I try to import it, I got these errors:

```
  from version import __version__
       ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'version'

  from itertools import izip_longest
        ImportError: cannot import name 'izip_longest' from 'itertools' (unknown location)
```

[Failed to install package 'version'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c9t9E.png)

I checked this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38634810/failing-to-import-itertools-in-python-3-5-2) and the accepted answer shows that `izip_longest` was renamed to `zip_longest` and that's why I can't import the module 'version'

Is there any way to get around this problem and import the module version in PyCharm?

Comment: Actually use Python 2.7?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I'm using Python 3.7.4

Comment: Well that's why, that module doesn't support Python 3

Answer (score 3):

Version 0.1.1 of [`version`](https://pypi.org/project/version/) released on PyPI is not compatible with Python 3. The [latest Github version](https://github.com/keleshev/version/commit/d4b32b62f3641cf907e8e44e1d421fdac88f3413) is, but has [not been released as its own version on PyPI yet](https://github.com/keleshev/version/issues/11). You'll have to explicitly install the Github version; on the command line that'd be:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/keleshev/version.git
```

Overall, that package looks pretty dead, and you may be better off looking for a maintained package that does the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Bit late for this and there may be things about the `version` package which are worthwhile.

But, chasing this "cannot import name 'izip_longest'" error, I realised that in fact that the PyPi package I really needed (and had used before) was [packaging](https://pypi.org/project/packaging/), not *version*. `packaging` has a module `version` and a class [packaging.version.Version](https://packaging.pypa.io/en/stable/version.html#packaging.version.Version).